# Why I am unable to see any electrical conductivity in Permalloy nano powders?

Tags: metal, materials, metallurgy

We recently purchased some permalloy nano powders (Ni80Fe70Mo3) I checked the electrical conductivity of these powders using a multimeter which can measure resistance to the order of giga ohm's. I was able to see electrical conductivity in carbonyl iron powders. While we were not expecting to see high electrically conductivity we expected to see some conductivity. I am wondering if I am missing something here or are these powders the issue.

Answer (score 11):

Nanoparticles are often [pyrophoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrophoricity), and may be coated to prevent spontaneous combustion. The particles' surface might be nitrided, or oxide coated, or coated with an organic chemical. [Permalloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalloy) itself is quite conductive, but the coatings are insulators.

One doesn't think of a lump of iron as flammable -- but sprinkle iron filings in a flame to make a "sparkler". [Steel wool](https://www.lomography.com/magazine/338587-steel-wool-photo-long-exposure-guide-with-lomo-instant-square-glass-camera) is effective kindling.

Check with the source of your permalloy powder to see if they're coated, and what that coating is.

Comment: Thermite: iron oxide powder + aluminum powder + heat = iron + aluminum oxide + **lots** of heat.

Comment: Also, uranium.  It's pyrophoricity + self-sharpening attributes are part of what makes DU soooo effective in cannons.